# GFCI breaker pops only when a specific other breaker is enabled?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci

My mother had a NEMA 14-50R outlet installed outside her house so I'd have a place to charge my EV. The outlet connects to her breaker panel via a 50 amp 2-pole GFCI breaker. Unfortunately, the breaker pops shortly after the vehicle is plugged in, so it's been unusable.

Today I decided to do some debugging. I turned off all the breakers except the one for the EV outlet, plugged in the car, and everything worked! One by one I turned the other breakers on, and as soon as I turned on one particular breaker, the GFCI breaker popped. I turned off the Problem Breaker, reset the EV outlet breaker, and successfully turned on every other breaker in the house without blowing anything. But again, when I turned on the Problem Breaker, the EV outlet breaker popped.

Does anyone have an idea of why this might happen? I'm assuming that the Problem Breaker is causing the EV outlet breaker to detect a ground fault, but I don't understand what that might mean or how to fix it.

As additional context, the Problem Breaker is a regular (no AFCI/GFCI protection) 15 amp double-pole breaker. It provides power to two of the bedrooms, which appear to be on some kind of MWBC? The circuit leaving the Problem Breaker has 5 wires: red and black (connected to the two poles), white and white with a red stripe (connected to the neutral bar) and bare copper (connected to the ground bar). From my brief Googling, I would have expected the MWBC to only have one neutral, but I'm no expert.

Comment: I imagine you have conduit to carry the wires and not cable(wires encase in plastic covering).  It sounds like two separate circuits with one ground instead of a true MWBC(with one neutral).

Comment: Strange. Can you upload a picture of the panel showing all wires going to the 14-50 and to the "linked" circuit? For future reference, if you hardwire an actual "charger" *instead of* a receptacle then you don't need the receptacle and, more importantly, then you don't need the GFCI breaker - the savings pays for a good chunk of the EVSE (charger) cost.

Comment: Are there any other GFCI/AFCI breakers in the panel?  There probably is a ground fault in one(or both) of the bedroom circuits, but not being near water/moisture(sinks) has gone unnoticed/people do not make a good connection to feel a shock.  It might be hard to find.

Comment: This sounds like two circuits in one conduit rather than a MWBC. Any chance you can find the first device on this circuit and disconnect it there, then add in a device at a time? It's going to be a hunt but maybe you'll find the ground fault.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems to me like some circuit is stealing neutral off your EVSE ("charger")  breaker.